# Developing Ilford Pan F Plus in TMax developer

Tags: negative-film

I developed a roll of PanF Plus in TMax developer using the 1:4 dilution at 4 minutes as recommended by Massive Development. The negatives look uniformly thin. I suspect the development time needs to be longer. Has anyone used TMax on PanF Plus and what were your results?

Comment: What temperature?

Comment: How old is the TMax? How long since the bottle was first opened and exposed to air? How has it been stored since the bottle was opened? In a container with air also inside, or in a smaller container with very little to no air inside?

Comment: Developer temp 68 degrees F per the recommendation. Developer is fresh - new bottle, opened only week before. Stored in a dark area with excess air squeezed out as the unused volume decreases.